# Why are the calls doubling each time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Shown here: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7huyh420/)

This is the code we're concerned with:

```
    doit1();

    function doit2(){
        $("#evtTarget").on("click", function(evt) {
            $("#evtTarget").addClass("highlighted");
            $("#evtTarget").on("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
            $("#evtTarget").html("<p>You Turned on the hover effect!</p>");
            doit1();
        });}

    function doit1(){
        $("#evtTarget").on("click", function(evt) {
            $("#evtTarget").off("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
            $("#evtTarget").html("<p>You shut off the hover effect!</p>");
            $("#evtTarget").removeClass("highlighted");
            console.log("check");
            doit2();
        });}
```

Something about this code, which I can't figure out, calls back and forth and doubles the call each time. This eventually breaks the page. Why is this and how do I do it better?

Comment: `doit1();` will be invoked every time click event takes place on `#evtTarget` and vice versa..

Comment: You are never unregistering your events...

Comment: Thanks. How can I fix the issue? I do want it invoked at certain times, I don't get why it's calling so many times when I call it once per click event.

Comment: you are calling it on all click events forever :)

Comment: I see, thank you very much.

Comment: Every time you call on(), you're adding a function to the list of functions to be called when the event occurs (even if that function is already being called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both functions, change `$("#evtTarget").on("click", function(evt) {` To `$("#evtTarget").off( "click" ).on("click", function(evt) {`

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks! So this "unregistered" the click events and re-registered them to prevent them from being called over and over? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the `off("click")` unbinds all previously bound  `click` events

Comment: Awesome. Been stuck for ages. Very helpful. Glad to have a better understanding of how this works.

Comment: @user3055938 I believe you could also have used one() instead of on() and left everything else the same

Comment: @Tibrogargan That's the strangest thing. I could have sworn that was one of the very first things I tried and it didn't work. But I just double-checked and what do you know haha. That's a tad frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is sort of "reentrant"... You only need to set your *onClick* once...

Try:

```
$(function() {
  turnItOn();

  $("#evtTarget").on("click", function(evt) {
    if ($("#evtTarget").hasClass("highlighted")) {
      turnItOff();
    } else {
      turnItOn();
    }
  });
});
function turnItOn() {
  $("#evtTarget").addClass("highlighted");
  $("#evtTarget").on("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
  $("#evtTarget").html("<p>You Turned on the hover effect!</p>");
}

function turnItOff() {
  $("#evtTarget").off("mouseover mouseleave", highlight);
  $("#evtTarget").html("<p>You shut off the hover effect!</p>");
  $("#evtTarget").removeClass("highlighted");
}

function highlight(evt) {
  $("#evtTarget").toggleClass("highlighted");
}
```

As seen in this version of you fiddle:

[https://jsfiddle.net/pnz9eooz](https://jsfiddle.net/pnz9eooz/)

Or turn the events off, like Alon suggested while I was writing this :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the extra solution. Glad to have another method/perspective to consider in the future.